# Golang HTTP server timeout

Tags: ruby, http, timeout, go, amazon-elb

I'm trying to write a web server in golang to handle geocoding requests.  Some of these requests take longer than a minute to process. In this case, the server seems to be returning an empty body to the client, though the handler keeps running.  I've tried the code below to no avail.  Am I missing something?  Is it possible this is a problem with [pat](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/pat)?

```
r := pat.New()

r.Get("/geocode", GeocodeHandler)
r.Get("/status", StatusHandler)
r.Get("/", InvalidHandler)

s := &http.Server{
    Addr: ":"+port,
    Handler: r,
    ReadTimeout: 10 * time.Minute,
    WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Minute,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 0,
}

s.ListenAndServe()
```

The client is in ruby.  I don't believe that's the problem though, since I see similar behavior if I use curl.

```
uri = URI(URI.escape("http://blah.com/geocode?address=#{address}"))
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.read_timeout = 10 * 60
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))
```

Comment: Check if your client is timing out.

Comment: Is the empty body being returned before the request has completed processing? Or does the processing finish and then the empty body is returned? This should hopefully indicate if the timeout is on the server or client side.

Comment: @Tom : I'm having the same issue if I use curl as the client. I've attached the ruby client though for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. I didn't mention that my server was behind an Amazon ELB. Its default timeout is 60 seconds.

Comment: Also default HTTP timeout is generally 2 minutes.

Comment: Amazon just added support for configuring timeouts: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/