# I think my file upload connection is closing...why?

Tags: http, go

*Disclaimer: I'm not sure if the title is my actual problem, but it's the only reason that makes sense for what's below.*

**Scenario**

I am uploading large videos to my Golang server. I have an 8GB file that takes roughly 15 minutes locally and works well. However, on my staging server (Google Cloud) this file takes a little over an hour to upload and this is where the problem hits.

**Problem**

My client is waiting on the file to finish uploading in order to call another API endpoint, but only on the staging server does it fail. So it seems like when my server is looking to write the response, then the connection won't allow it because the client shows a `502` error and a CORS error, which I know is Chrome's way of saying "We don't know, check your server".

**Code**

Inside my `SrcHandler` is this:

```golang
defer func(begin time.Time) {
        pr, pw := io.Pipe()
        defer pw.Close()

        if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
            return
        }

        srcFile, handler, err := r.FormFile("video")
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "INVALID_FILE", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        defer srcFile.Close()

        // Copy uploaded file to *PipeWriter
        go func() {
            defer srcFile.Close()
            defer pw.Close()
            io.Copy(pw, srcFile)
        }()

        // Prep fileName
        var srcFileName = strings.Replace(handler.Filename, " ", "_", -1)
        var extension = filepath.Ext(srcFileName)
        srcFileName = srcFileName[0 : len(srcFileName)-len(extension)]

        // Create temp file to write too
        f, err := ioutil.TempFile("./tmp/pending", srcFileName+"_")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()

        // Copy *PipeReader to temp file
        io.Copy(f, pr)

        contentType, err := getFileContentType("./" + f.Name())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Content Type Error: %v\n", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("ContentType = %v\n ", contentType)
        if contentType != "video/x-flv" && contentType != "video/mp4" &&
            contentType != "video/quicktime" && contentType != "video/x-msvideo" &&
            contentType != "video/x-ms-wmv" && contentType != "video/webm" {
            http.Error(w, "INVALID_FILE_TYPE", http.StatusBadRequest)
            os.Remove(f.Name())
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("Upload path -> %v\n", f.Name())
        upload := UploaderResponse{srcFileName, "./" + f.Name()}

        resp, err := json.Marshal(upload)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error using Marshal %v\n", err)
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

        status, err2 := w.Write(resp)
        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error when writing response to app %v\n", err2)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Status from uploading: %v\n", status)
        }

        _ = u.logger.Log("upload.Handler Duration ", time.Since(begin))

    }(time.Now())
```

The code gets down to the last line, `u.logger.Log()` which actually shows output. So the video is uploaded correctly...only responding to the client fails. Does anyone have ideas?

*Disclaimer 2: I just found out that `w.Write` returns an error, so I'm waiting on a file to finish uploading to see if I get an errors logged. Will respond with an update.*

## Update 1

I uploaded a new file and the `w.Write()` call works, returning a `91` integer. I'm not sure what the issue may be now. Could it be a time-out somewhere I don't know of. FYI, my server read and write timeouts are both 6 hours.

If it helps, here are the logs. It should be easy to follow the code with the outputs:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the pipe? Why not copy directly from srcFile to f?

Comment: I hired someone to do this a while ago and server coding isn't my strong suit. Would that have anything to do with why the response doesn't write?

Comment: Might not be related, but you're not handling the error from `json.Marshal`. Could be a source of bugs in the future.

Also, you may want to change the `Printf` calls to be `logger.Log` instead so that all output is consistent and in the same location.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks @Kyle.

Comment: After looking at it some more, the pipe code is probably not the cause of the problem. The pipe is unnecessary as is bunding this code in a defer function call.

Comment: That's good to know. I've had to simplify a lot more of the hire's code as well. I'm about to update the post in a few minutes as I'm expecting an error to show after the `w.Write()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the ballpark mentioning timeouts but it turns out this issue had nothing to do with the code. I stumbled upon another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690380/golang-http-server-timeout) that had the same problem but on AWS instead. The problem was a timeout from the load balancer. I used the instructions from [Google Cloud's docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#timeout-setting) to increase the timeout from a default of 30 secs to a couple of hours. To be specific, the timeout setting is a count for how long to wait on the server to send a response to the client.